# Upload to Google Drive without knowing size

Tags: java, file-upload, chunked-encoding, google-drive-api

I am attempting to upload a large (~512 MB) file to Google Drive via the API.

I would strongly prefer to use the Java SDK for its help with OAuth.

I am generating this file and streaming to Drive without storing it anywhere. In particular, this means I do not know the length of the file before sending it.

---

**Java SDK**

I have looked in the Java SDK, but I see no way to go this. `com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent` requires implementations to support `getLength()`.

---

**HTTP**

I see a reference to chunked transfer (which is made for exactly this situation) on https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads

> The most straightforward method for uploading a file is by making a simple upload request. This option is a good choice when:
>
> - The file is small enough to upload again in its entirety if the connection fails.
>     There is no metadata to send. This might be true if you plan to send metadata for this resource in a separate request, or if no metadata is supported or available.
>     To use simple upload, make a POST or PUT request to the method's /upload URI and add the query parameter uploadType=media. For example:
> - POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media
>
> The HTTP headers to use when making a simple upload request include:
>
> - Content-Type. Set to one of the method's accepted upload media data types, specified in the API reference.
> - Content-Length. Set to the number of bytes you are uploading. Not required if you are using chunked transfer encoding.

but it is only supposed to be used for "small" files. It seems to run counter to the point of chunked transfer encoding if it is only ever used for small files.

---

Can I send large files to Google Drive without knowing their size ahead of time?

Answer (score 1):

[Resumable uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#resumable)

"**X-Upload-Content-Length.** Set to the number of bytes of upload data to be transferred in subsequent requests.  If the length is unknown at the time of this request, you can omit this header."

Dig into Resumable uploads and you should be set.